# Error while trying to open files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file

My code has 2 parts. First part is an automatic file opening programmed like this :

```
fichierref = 'H:\MATLAB\Archive_08112012';
files = dir(fullfile(fichierref, '*.txt'));
numberOfFiles = numel(files);
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 11;
for d = 1:numberOfFiles
    filenames(d) = cellstr(files(d).name);
end

for i=1:numberOfFiles
    data = importdata(fullfile(fichierref,filenames{i}),delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
end
```

Later on, I want the user to select his files for analysis. There's a problem with this though. I typed the lines as follow :

```
reference = warndlg('Choose the files from which you want to know the magnetic field');
uiwait(reference);
filenames = cellstr(uigetfile('./*.txt','MultiSelect', 'on'));
numberOfFiles = numel(filenames);
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 11;
```

It's giving me the following error, after I press OK on the prompt:

```
Error using cellstr (line 34)  
Input must be a string.

Error in FreqVSChampB_no_spec (line 128)  
filenames = cellstr(uigetfile('./*.txt','MultiSelect', 'on'));
```

Anyone has an idea why it's doing that?

Comment: have you selected any file?

Comment: I could not. As soon as I press ok, the program stops and I get the error. It would normally open a window and I could select the programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `cellstr` command for the output of `uigetfile` in `'MultiSelect'`  mode: the output is already in a cellarray form (see doc of `uigetfile`).

Comment: @Marc-olivierLessard - do not edit your question in this manner. If you have a new error - then you should ask a new question (it would be nice if you link the questions for context). By this edit you change the meaning of the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194424/non-cell-array-with-uigetfile-in-matlab

Here's the new question :)