# Non-cell array with uigetfile in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

My code has 2 parts. First part is an automatic file opening programmed like this :

```
fichierref = 'H:\MATLAB\Archive_08112012';
files = dir(fullfile(fichierref, '*.txt'));
numberOfFiles = numel(files);
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 11;
for d = 1:numberOfFiles
    filenames(d) = cellstr(files(d).name);
end

for i=1:numberOfFiles
    data = importdata(fullfile(fichierref,filenames{i}),delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
end
```

Later on, I want the user to select his files for analysis. There's a problem with this though. I typed the lines as follow :

```
reference = warndlg('Choose the files from which you want to know the magnetic field');
uiwait(reference);
filenames = uigetfile('./*.txt','MultiSelect', 'on');
numberOfFiles = numel(filenames);
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 11;
```

It's giving me the following error, after I press OK on the prompt:

```
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in FreqVSChampB_no_spec (line 149)
data=importdata(filenames{1},delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

I didn't get the chance to select any text document. Anyone has an idea why it's doing that?

Comment: why do we need the first part of your code for this question?

Comment: I put in case something related could do the error. I didn't think the first part was related to it, but I prefered to put it to be sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216968/unable-to-open-a-file-with-uigetfile-in-matlab

Here is the last part (I hope) of my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uigetfile` is a bit of an annoying when used with `MultiSelect': when you select multiple files the output is returned as a cell array (of strings). **However**, when only one file is selected the output is of type string (**not** a cell array with a single cell, as one would have expected).

So, in order to fix this:

```
filenames = uigetfile('./*.txt','MultiSelect', 'on');
if ~iscell(filenames) && ischar( a )
    filenames = {filenames}; % force it to be a cell array of strings
end
% continue your code here treating filenames as cell array of strings.
```

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by @Sam one MUST verify that the user did not press 'cancel' on the UI (by checking that `filenames` is a string).

Comment: Also note that if nothing is successfully selected (perhaps you pressed Cancel), `filenames` is returned as an empty array, not cell array. Check for this as well.