# Unable to open a file with uigetfile in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I am building a code that lets the user open some files.

```
reference = warndlg('Choose the files for analysis.');
uiwait(reference);
filenames2 = uigetfile('./*.txt','MultiSelect', 'on');
if ~iscell(filenames2)
    filenames2 = {filenames2};    % force it to be a cell array of strings
end
numberOfFiles = numel(filenames2);

data = importdata(filenames2{i},delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

When I run the code, the prompts show up, I press OK, and then nothing happens. The code just stops, telling me :

```
Error using importdata (line 137)
Unable to open file.

Error in FreqVSChampB_no_spec (line 119)
data=importdata(filenames2{1},delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

I just don't have the opportunity to select a file. The cellarray stays empty as showed in the following image.

[image: Empty cell array]

Comment: I can't see any `importdata` in the code snippet you provide?

Comment: please see the edit to the previous answer - checking that the user did not press `cancel` in the `uigetfile` dialog.

Comment: I don't get why that information would be relevant in my actual problem. I see the point of adding it at some point, but I'm testing it myself and I am not pressing the cancel button.

The only way to test if Cancel was pressed would be to check if filenames2 == 0. But since it does that even if I press OK, this wouldn't give me any information.

Comment: You have a problem with `uigetfile`. run in debug mode and see that you get the filenames you selected. Try first without `MultiSelect.

Comment: That's the whole point. I don't get to select a file. I get the prompt, but I do not select a file. It just skips that part.

Comment: what happens when you type `uigetfile` in command window?

Comment: I should say Warning Dialog instead of prompt, this might be confusing.

I get the warning dialog, I press OK, and then the program skips the uigetfile part and goes directly to importdata

Comment: why do you need the warning dialog? why don't you use the title of the `uigetfile` dialog?

Comment: When I type in commandwindow, it opens normally and I can select a .m file.

Comment: Well, seems the removing the warning dialog solved the issue, I don't know why...

Comment: try creating the warndlg with 'modal' createmode - this should make the `uiwait` redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB can't find the file that you have selected. Your variable `filenames2` contains only the name of the file, not its full path. If you don't provide the full path to `importdata`, it will search for whatever file name you provide on the MATLAB path, and if it can't find it it will error as you see.

Try something like this - I'm just doing it with single selection for ease of description, but you can do something similar with multiple selection.

```
[fileName, pathName] = uigetfile('*.txt');
fullNameWithPath = fullfile(pathName, fileName);
importdata(fullNameWithPath)
```

`fullfile` is useful, as it inserts the correct character between `pathName` and `fileName` (`\` on Windows, `/` on Unix).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add

```
pause(0.1);
```

just after `uiwait(reference);`

For me it works. In fact I've noticed the active windows changes when we use uiwait and uigetfile.